# Checkbox style attribute does not changing from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have added `style="display:none"` to `CheckBox`. On `DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged` event I have changed to `display:block`. But its not changing to `block`.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Mark as close" style="display:none"/>
</div>

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string s = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
     if (s == "3")
     {
         CheckBox1.Style.Add("display", "block");
         //  CheckBox1.Attributes.Add("Style", "display:block");
     }
     else
     {
         CheckBox1.Style.Add("display", "none");                    
     }        
}
```

Comment: Did you debug code ? ? show .aspx code ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the *style* like below:-

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
    if (s == "3")
    {
       CheckBox1.Attributes["style"] = "display:block;";
    }
    else
    {
       CheckBox1.Attributes["style"] = "display:none;";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CheckBox1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");
```

Comment: No luck.not working..I  have placed the checkbox inside update panel